# Hibernate sessionManager with Tapestry

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

I need some help please. I am getting this error while trying to store some form data into my database, using tapestry 5.3.6, hibernate 4.1.7.Final and Mysql 5.1.21
Actually the data are stored in the database but i still have the error after i click the submit button.

### error

> [ERROR] ioc.Registry Error invoking method public static org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateSessionManager org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateCoreModule.buildHibernateSessionManager(org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateSessionSource,org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.PerthreadManager): org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
> [ERROR] ioc.Registry Operations trace:
> [ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 1] Triggering event 'action' on address/Create:beaneditform.form
> [ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 2] Triggering event 'success' on address/Create:beaneditform.form
> [ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 3] Instantiating service HibernateSessionManager implementation via org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateCoreModule.buildHibernateSessionManager(HibernateSessionSource, PerthreadManager) (at HibernateCoreModule.java:96)
> [ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 4] Constructing service implementation via org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateCoreModule.buildHibernateSessionManager(HibernateSessionSource, PerthreadManager) (at HibernateCoreModule.java:96)
> [INFO] AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 2872 ms

### pom.xml

I have added the following dependecies to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
   
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would be happy for any help.
thanks

Will

Answer (score 1):

I dont think tapestry-hibernate 5.3.X is compatible with Hibernate 4.X.

Try to use latest release of 3.X